# Compatible for RxJs is Spring reactor or RxJava

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-boot, rxjs, rxjs5

UI -Angular JS screen has to be a non blocking page, so we are using RxJS oberverable but not sure what we need to have in backend services to subscribe and publish the request from/to UI (whether we should go with Spring Reactor or RxJava)